# Convexity properties of a cone

Tags: convex-analysis, normed-spaces

Let $M$ be a normed space and $A$ a subset (nonempty) of the unit sphere ($S_1$, which is the points of norm $1$). Define, for $\alpha >0$, a $A^{\alpha}=\{x\in S_1 | d\left( x,A\right) \leq\alpha\}$. What can we say about the following properties of $A^\alpha$:

- closedness
- convexity
- $A\subset A^\alpha$
- conic hull of $A^\alpha$ convexity ?

My attempt is in what follows:

- We see that $A^\alpha$ is $f^{-1}(0,\alpha)$, where $f$ is the inverse function of the distance function to the set $A$. Since $f^{-1}$ is continuous, it follows that $A^\alpha$ is closed.
- The set $A^\alpha$ is convex if and only if $A$ is a singleton because because the distance is so.
- $A$ is a subset of $A^\alpha$ from definition.
- I write the definition of conic hull and convexity, but I do not get anything.
  Thank you for any observation.

Comment: How do you define convexity in a general metric space?  The unit sphere?

Comment: I made a correction. It is about a normed space. I think now is ok, it make sense to define convexity as usual.

Comment: Denote by $d_A : M \to \mathbb R$ the distance function to $A$. It is continuous, but does not have an inverse function $f$. What you mean is that the preimage $d_A^{-1}([0,\alpha])$ is closed because $d_A$ is continuous.

Comment: Convexity: Consider $M = \mathbb  R$ with the absolute value as norm. If $A = \{ -1,1 \}$ and $\alpha \ge 1$, then $A^\alpha$ is convex.

Comment: The conic hull of $A^α$ can be non-convex. For instance, when  $M=\Bbb R^2$ endowed with Euclidean norm, $A=\{(-1,0), (1,0)\}$, and $\alpha=1$.